# Woocommerce Customer Details moved in Version 3.2?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

We have been using the email notifications from Woocommerce, and it broke part of the notifications with the new update to 3.2, and I don't know how to fix. I look at the file, "class-wc-emails.php" (woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php) place where the email notification is being generated, and it has an ambiguous message that says, "In versions prior to 3.2 this was used for notes, phone and email but this data has moved."

I look back into our saved archive site, and it has this code that appears to call the notes, phone, and email that I'm looking to add back to the notifications

```
    // Code prior to 3.2
    $fields = array();

    if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
        $fields['customer_note'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Note', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ),
        );
    }

    if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) {
        $fields['billing_email'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_email() ),
        );
    }

    if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) {
        $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_phone() ),
        );
    }
```

I tried to include that, but did not seem to add the notes, phone, and email to my email notifications.. Does anyone know what I need to do to get Customer Details (notes, phone, and email) to show up in our notifications of new orders?

Comment: Which specific email notification are you referring to?  Customer or admin?

Comment: Admin notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add in extra fields to show in the order email via the `woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 'add_woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields', 10, 3 );

function add_woocommerce_email_customer_details_fields( $fields, $sent_to_admin, $order ) {

    if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
        $fields['customer_note'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Note', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ),
        );
    }

    if ( $order->get_billing_email() ) {
        $fields['billing_email'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_email() ),
        );
    }

    if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) {
        $fields['billing_phone'] = array(
            'label' => __( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ),
            'value' => wptexturize( $order->get_billing_phone() ),
        );
    }

    return $fields;
}
```